# VueJS: Using x-template for a sub-component inside a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am not correctly understanding the usage pattern for using x-template for a subcomponent inside a vuejs component.

So, I have a component called CategoryNav.vue which has a template. Within that to display a list, we have used an x-template. But I render my page, it doesn't recognize this component created using the x-template. I think i am using it incorrectly. Any help is appreciated. Here is my main component code.

**CategoryNav.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="">
  <menu-list :items="treeList"></menu-list>
</div>
</template>

<script type="text/x-template" id="menu-list-template">
  <ul v-if="items.length">
    <li v-for="item of items">
      <a :href="item.value">{{ item.label }}{{ item.id }}</a>
      <menu-list :items="item.children"></menu-list>
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>
<script>
const MenuList = {
  name: 'menu-list',
  template: '#menu-list-template',
  props: ['items']
}

export default {
  name: 'category-nav',
  components: {
    MenuList
  },
  computed: {
    list () {
      return this.$store.state.topics
    },
    treeList () {
      const items = this.list.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { children: [] }))
      const byValue = new Map(items.map(item => [item.value, item]))
      const topLevel = []
      for (const item of items) {
        const parent = byValue.get(item.parent)
        if (parent) {
          parent.children.push(item)
        } else {
          topLevel.push(item)
        }
      }
      return topLevel
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work. `<script type="text/x-template" id="menu-list-template">` needs to exist in the DOM somewhere for Vue to find it, and since it is outside of the `<template>` section, `vue-loader` is going to treat it as a [custom block](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/custom-blocks.html) (which will be ignored by default).

A single *.vue file is meant to contain one component only. I don't recommend mixing x-templates with `vue-loader` anyway. You should put every component into a *.vue file so that it gets precompiled, that way you don't need to bundle the vue compiler in your production build.

You can either:

1. (Recommended) Extract the sub component into its own *.vue file and import it into the `CategoryNav.vue` module.
2. You can define the sub component completely within `CategoryNav.vue` `<script>` section, but it cannot have a compiled template. You'll have to specify the render function for it (messy).
3. Same as #2, except you can specify the template as a string, but you will need to ship the Vue compiler in your production build. If you want to use an x-template instead of a string, then you need to make sure that the x-template `<script>` is in the DOM.

See [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/dist) for an explanation of the Vue build files.

Comment: I used the first approach, that is, to extract the sub component in a separate file of its own and it is working correctly. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare component name '**menu-list**', let's try this:

```
export default {
  name: 'category-nav',
  components: {
    'menu-list': MenuList
  },
....
```